# Select values from list based on bools in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, performance

For each sublist in array `b`, return values from list `a` with same position as positive boolean in `b` sublist (i.e. where True).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])  # values to choose from
b = np.array([[False, True, False, True, False],  # based on bools
              [False, False, False, False, False]])

out = []
for i, v in enumerate(b):
    out.append([])
    for j in range(len(e)):
        if v[j]:
            out[i].append(a[j])

out = np.array(out)  # np.array([[3,7],[]])  # result

# In first sublist, True is on index 1 and 3 which corresponds to values 3 and 7.
# In second sublist, there is not True, hence empty.
```

The above seems too laborious and it is possibly not making use of numpy vectorization (it is slow on large data).

Comment: While `a[b[0]` uses the fast compiled numpy code, you can't get a list, or array, of lists/arrays that differ in size with `numpy` "vectorization".  That "vectorization" means using compiled numpy methods/functions, and those (nearly) always work with whole arrays, and return whole arrays.  An object dtype array is virtually the same as a list, and is not created or processed at those fast "vectorized" speeds.

Comment: @hpaulj is it be possible to convert the above the "whole array"? It is quite difficult to grasp what makes whole arrays different. Is it because of different sizes of `a (1 by m)` and `b (n by m)`? Simple vectorization like df['a'] = 2 * df['b'] is `1 by m` and `1 by m`.

Comment: I'll try to illustrate what I mean in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Series` is 1d; `b` is a 2d array.  The `Series` also has row indices, which a plain array does not.

```
In [70]: a.shape, b.shape
Out[70]: ((5,), (2, 5))

In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4    9
dtype: int64
```

We can use rows of `b`, 1d array of shape (5,) to select elements from `a`:

```
In [72]: a[b[0,:]]
Out[72]: 
1    3
3    7
dtype: int64

In [73]: a[b[1,:]]
Out[73]: Series([], dtype: int64)
```

Since the rows produce different length results, we can't do that selection in one step.  `a[b]` gives an error, with the mismatch between (5,) and (2,).

It may be simpler to work with the array version of `a`, also 1d, but without row indices:

```
In [103]: A = a.to_numpy(); A
Out[103]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], dtype=int64)
```

Applying a row of `b` to index that:

```
In [104]: A[b[0]]
Out[104]: array([3, 7], dtype=int64)
```

And iteratively doing that for all rows:

```
In [105]: [A[row] for row in b]
Out[105]: [array([3, 7], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64)]
```

We can make a (2,5) array from `A`, and apply the `b` boolean mask - but the result will be 1d, with no indication that the 2nd row did not select anything:

```
In [106]: np.vstack((A,A))
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
       [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]], dtype=int64)

In [107]: np.vstack((A,A))[b]
Out[107]: array([3, 7], dtype=int64)
```

Indexing with a row of `b` or `b` itself is what I was calling a 'whole-array' operation.  But using the rows of `b` individually can't be done that way; it requires a Python level iteration.

There are some other ways of working with `A` and `b`:

Multiplication works, where `b` is treated as an array of 0 and 1s:

```
In [111]: A*b
Out[111]: 
array([[0, 3, 0, 7, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

There's is also a `masked array` subclass of arrays:

```
In [112]: np.ma.masked_array(np.vstack((A,A)),~b)
Out[112]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 3, --, 7, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --]],
  mask=[[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=999999,
  dtype=int64)
```

The [105] list of arrays can turned into an `object` dtype array:

```
In [115]: np.array([A[row] for row in b],object)
Out[115]: array([array([3, 7], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64)], dtype=object)
```

This is 1d, with shape (2,).  Sometimes its useful, but performance wise it is not an improvement over the list.

Comment: This is a super comprehensive reply and an excellent source for learning. Thank you for effort put in.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use:

```
a2 = a.to_numpy()
out = [a2[x] for x in b]
```

output: `[array([3, 7]), array([], dtype=int64)]`

Comment: Neat. I assume the comprehension makes use of some C++ proc, so as fast as it can get / not slower than numpy magic methods.

Comment: No, list comprehensions are using python (they are nevertheless quite fast), but anyway you have to loop in your case as you can't generate a ragged array.

Comment: I must accept hpaulj's answer as it provides more detail, given https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. Nonetheless your answer is exceptionally simple.